# How to save login information from database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm creating very simple ATM machine.

At the beginning, user is asked about login and password.
If password is correct then user can make some operations.

Now it has operations like:
1) withdraw money
2) deposit money
3) current value

The problem is that every time when I select 1) or 2) or 3), the program asks me about login and password again. But I want to be asked only once at beginning.

So I need solution which allows me to save somewhere user login name / password and read it when I want to do some operations.

It's part of my code.

```
public class LoginVerification {

public static void login() throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter USER ID:");
    String userId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter PIN CODE:");
    String pass = input.nextLine();

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Info WHERE ClientID = ? AND ClientPass = ?";

        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        posted.setString(1, userId);
        posted.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet resultSet = posted.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        int rowCount = resultSet.getInt(1);

        if (rowCount == 1) {
            System.out.println("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
            Helper.showMainMenu();

        } else {
            System.out.println("#LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL, WRONG LOGIN OR PASSWORD");

            System.out.println("\nTry again? \n1) yes \n2) no [quit]");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                login();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And the problem is below. As you can see the program is asking again about login/pass because I have no idea how can I do it in a different way.

```
public static void withdraw() throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter USER ID:");
    String userId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("please enter PIN CODE:");
    String pass = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("how much you want to withdraw");
    int money = input.nextInt();

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        String sql = "UPDATE BankDB.Info SET `Money`= `Money` - ? WHERE `ClientID`= ? AND `ClientPass` = ?";

        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        posted.setInt(1, money);
        posted.setString(2, userId);
        posted.setString(3, pass);

        if (posted.executeUpdate() > 0) {
            System.out.println("OPERATION SUCCESSFUL");
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL");

            System.out.println("\nTry again? \n1) yes \n2) no [quit]");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                withdraw();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use flags and check whenever necessary

Comment: Once you login, you need to maintain the session for that user. ie by setting a boolean variable. And for all operations, you need to check if that variable is true or not. But looking at your code, it doesn't look like you are doing it the right way.

Comment: have the `userid` and `pass` as fields on the class - not local variables - then you can check to see if they have been set

Comment: actually in some scenarios  login before actual operation is a good idea or even required. Imagine user had logged in, then got distracted and someone else would have access to operations? Some ATMs require enter a pin-code after request of transaction, chip based cards get queried   without notice. Your problem is though, in that you seen to close session after logging in. The connection is lifetime of active login.

Comment: Thank you guys for tips. Could you give me short code example which solve this problem? I'm on the very beginning of programming and it's hard for me to use your advices in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a flag to tell if user is logged in or not,
this can be set in `login()` and can be checked/used from any page

modify `login()` as below:

1- define a class-scope variable in `LoginVerification` class

```
private static boolean loggedIn = false;
```

first line in `login()`, check that flag

```
public static void login() throws Exception {

        if(loggedIn){
            //do nothing, user already logged in
            return;
        }
//...rest of code ...
```

add this when you find out user login is correct or not:

```
if (rowCount == 1) {
    //add this line
    loggedIn = true;
} else {
    //add this line
    loggedIn = false;
}
```

now in every other place that need user to be logged in, use

```
LoginVerification.login();
```

ex, replace this

```
public static void withdraw() throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter USER ID:");
    String userId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("please enter PIN CODE:");
    String pass = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("how much you want to withdraw");// rest of code
```

with this:

```
public static void withdraw() throws Exception {
    LoginVerification.login();
    System.out.println("how much you want to withdraw"); // rest of code
```

user will be asked to login if user is not logged in already.